# GIT replacement for web based development environment

Tags: git, file, github

Basically I have a set of computers set up with custom software. developers that use this software to work on task for the company. Currently we use GIT for branching to work on issues and syncing changes and all the usual git stuff as well as the software using git labels to keep track of releases etc.

We want to rebuild this software as a web based platform running on a server that the developers can connect too. But that would mean 1 file system so concurrent editing would be an issue.

The best solution I have is to have a clone of the repos in a different sub directory for each user but I would relay rather not do that as it would be incredibly inefficient as the repos we work on are several gig.

Any help, ideas or advice would be immensely appreciated.

Edit:
For clarity, I love git and I am happy with it. But due to a large number of factors running the application on each pc is not an option anymore so I want tosm way of getting the benefits of git for each developer but through my cloud based application.

Comment: One of the major benefits of git is its distributed nature. Why on earth would you want all of your developers sharing one filesystem through a Web interface?

Comment: @wickstopher thats the point, I don't. I want to make my application "cloud" based and still retain the distributed nature I have by leting them run the application on there pc and using git.